# Saving Payment Processor directs to 404 page / Payment Processor Card Options Hidden

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, stripe

I've noticed a few odd symptoms but I'm not sure what the cause is:

- When I try to save the Payment Processor add/edit page, I get a 404 page (although the information does save).
- When adding a Payment Processor, the Card Type Options are hidden, although the description is still there (see screenshot below) - this is when adding the Stripe option, but not Stripe Checkout or PayPal
- If we try to add more than one Payment Processor to a Contribution Page, the options are hidden in the form for anonymous users, but there are no specific permissions that would affect this, so we can't submit the form (it's a required field). This happens regardless of which two options we offer, e.g. PayPal and Stripe Checkout

None of this is leaving anything useful in the logs so that's not much help.

It's currently running CiviCRM 5.62.1 and WordPress 6.3.1

[image: Screenshot of Payment Processor page showing the description field but no options for the Credit Card Types]

Any suggestions for where to look?

Comment: Just noting that I've seen the save the Payment Processor add/edit page issue here as well: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45178/cannot-add-or-edit-a-payment-processor-without-error-membership-contribution-f. On 5.65.1 add/edit pages are just blank. I resolved the other issues on that post.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is likely related to [this issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4418), which was fixed in 5.63. Can you try upgrading to at least 5.63.4? There was a security release last week anyways and that's the minimum version to get the security updates.

Comment: I have run the upgrade and the Accepted Credit Card is back, and I can save without landing on a 404 - I had to re-add the Stripe Payment Processor but it was perfect second time around.... However I still can't see options on the Contribution page when I'm not logged in. The Stripe payment fields are not visible for anonymous users? I have the "CiviContribute: make online contributions" ticked in the permissions.

Comment: And Access AJAX API?

Comment: Good thinking but it's already ticked...